# message properties dynamic key

Tags: dynamic, properties, key

Is it possible to have dynamic keys (not values) in message properties. Something like:

```
error.required.{0}= This field is required.
```

It might not be standard approach, but I have scenario where it kind of makes sense for me to do that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Generally it would be something like:

```
error.required[{0}] = 'This field is required'
```

Clarifying which language you're using would help.

Comment: Thanks! Jordon. im using java.

Comment: @Jordon: Still not sure ..does the above convention work in java

Comment: Yes, it does, except that instead of {0} you would have the variable name, and you of course need a semicolon at the end.